# Call a superclass' constructor with new Array or ArrayList that contains data?

Tags: java, arrays, inheritance, constructor, arraylist

I am trying to call a superclass' constructor, with either an ArrayList(preferred) or array that already has information in it. I don't know what my syntactical mistake is, or if you can even do it?

I specifically want to insert "true" and "false" into either object. Just those two.

```
public class TrueFalseQuestion extends MultipleChoiceQuestion
{
    Answer myAnswer;
    StringPrompt myPrompt;

    //I can create, but not initialize data up here, correct?
    //Tried creating an ArrayList, but cannot insert the strings before calling constructor

    public TrueFalseQuestion()
    {
        /* Want to call parent constructor with "true" and "false" in array or ArrayList already*/
        super(new String["true", "false"]);
        ...
    }
```

I have a feeling this is a facepalm-er but I just cant figure it out. I've tried various ways, but the pain is the fact the super constructor MUST be called first, thus not giving me a chance to initialize the data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the format:

```
super(new String[] {"true", "false"});
```

if `MultipleChoiceQuestion` contains a constructor like this:

```
MultipleChoiceQuestion(String[] questionArray)
```

If it contains an overloaded constructor with a `List` argument as you say, for example:

```
MultipleChoiceQuestion(List<String> questionList)
```

then you can use:

```
super(Arrays.asList("true", "false"));
```

or if there a requirement for `ArrayList` to be used:

```
super(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "true", "false" })));
```

Comment: Thank you :) Do you know if it can be done with ArrayList too?

Comment: Just added it. Hope this helps.

Comment: `Arrays.asList` returns a `List`, not an `ArrayList`. (And in the current implementation, the actual object returned is not an instance of `ArrayList`; it's an instance of the private class `Arrays.ArrayList`.)

Answer (score 4):

If you have any control of the MultipleChoiceQuestion class you could change the constructor to this instead:

```
public MultipleChoiceQuestion(String ... values) {}
```

You'd then be able to call it like this:

```
public TrueFalseQuestion() {
    super("true", "false");
}
```

This is called varargs if you haven't heard about them before. You can read about it here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Comment: That was helpful. Thank you! I can't decide on which implementation to use. That might be best.

Comment: It gives you quite a lot of freedom. You can still send in an array to the constructor. Both ways will work.

Answer (score 3):

```
super(new String[]{"true", "false"});
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to do it with ArrayList as well?

Comment: @iaacp yes, `super(Arrays.asList("true", "false"));` could be used as Reimeus suggested.

Answer (score 2):

For a `List` (not specifically an `ArrayList`), you can do this:

```
super(Arrays.asList("true", "false"));
```

If you need specifically an `Arraylist<String>`, you will need to do this:

```
super(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"true", "false"})));
```